# Download starting and ending bytes of remote file with java

Tags: java, download

I'm wondering if it's possible to download the starting and ending 128 bytes of a given remote file in java. If so where would I begin?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by understand the source of my download.  Is it a HTTP service which supports partial downloads for example?  Is it a service you have written?

Comment: Yes it would support partial downloads.

Comment: You are developing the client and server or just the client ?